# Remove u' from ansible output

Tags: ansible

Having an issue with the output I am getting from running my playbook.
How can I turn the debug output - `H/W Version     : 1.0` into `HW Version: 1.0`

and how can I clean up the output file to remove the u' and []

```
more /tmp/sw-facts
```

`Hostname: switch Version: 5.2(1)N1(3)  Hardware: [u'H/W Version     : 1.0'] Serial: 000000000`

> PLAY [Research]
>
> TASK [Stage 1 gathering version & HW info] 
>   ok: [switch]
>
> TASK [Stage 2 collect ansible facts] 
>   ok: [switch]
>
> TASK [Stage 3 validating output from network device] 
>   ok: [switch] =>
>     msg:
>     - - 'H/W Version     : 1.0'
>     - 5.2(1)N1(3)
>
> TASK [write some facts to disk after formatting] 
>   ok: [switch]

```
---
# This playbook will retrieve version & hw info from Nexus switches 
- name: Research
  hosts: lab
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Stage 1 gathering version & HW info
      nxos_command:
        commands:
          - "show sprom sup | inc 'H/W Version'"
      register: output

    - name: Stage 2 collect ansible facts
      nxos_facts:
        gather_subset: hardware
      register: version

    - name: Stage 3 validating output from network device
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ output.stdout }}"
          - "{{ ansible_net_version }}"

    - name: write some facts to disk after formatting
      copy:
        content: |
          #jinja2: lstrip_blocks: True
            {% for host in groups['lab'] if hostvars[host]['ansible_net_hostname'] is defined %}
            Hostname: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_net_hostname }} Version: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_net_version }}  Hardware: {{ hostvars[host].output.stdout }} Serial: {{ hostvars[host].ansible_ne$
            {% endfor %}
        dest: /tmp/sw-facts
      run_once: yes
```

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: -sh-4.1$ ansible --version
ansible 2.6.7
python version = 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May 22 2015, 08:34:51) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-15)]

Comment: I amended the nxos_command to: "show sprom sup | inc 'H/W Version' | cut -c 19-22"

Comment: Your problem is that `stdout` as returned by many networking modules is actually a list, so you want `stdout[0]`.  That's why you see `[u'H/W Version     : 1.0']` in your output; those brackets are showing you that you have a single-item list.

Answer (score 0):

I amended the nxos_command to: "show sprom sup | inc 'H/W Version' | cut -c 19-22"

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from using Python 2. If you can't switch to Python 3, you can use `to_yaml` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/to_yaml_filter.html), so your output would look like: `[H/W Version     : 1.0]`.