# How to remove u' from ansible list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, unicode-string

In my playbook, I am trying to get list of sub-directory names using the find module and then extracting the basename from path.  I have been able to get the list but the elements are prepended with `u'`. How can I remove those from the output?

Ansible version 2.9

I tried to look at these SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174545/how-to-remove-u-from-list-output-in-ansible) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839072/remove-u-from-ansible-output), but couldn't get it to work.
I may not have fully understood how they should be applied

This is part of my playbook:

```yaml
- name: set item.path | basename
  set_fact: dir_name_list2_basename="{{ item.path | basename}}"
  with_items: "{{ zookeeper_data_dir.files}}"
  register: item_path_basename_list

- debug: 
    msg: "{{item_path_basename_list.results}}"

- name: debug item.path | basename as list 
  debug: 
    var: item.ansible_facts.dir_name_list2_basename
  with_items: "{{item_path_basename_list.results}}"


- debug: msg="item_path_basename_list.results {{ item_path_basename_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.dir_name_list2_basename') | list }}"

- name: set fact to array 
  set_fact: basename_array="{{ item_path_basename_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.dir_name_list2_basename') | list }}"

- debug: 
    msg: "basename_array &&&&&&&& {{basename_array}}"
```

And this is the output of the last `debug`:

```json
ok: [zk3-dev] => {
    "msg": "basename_array &&&&&&&& [u'version-2_backup', u'version-2']"
}
ok: [zk2-dev] => {
    "msg": "basename_array &&&&&&&& [u'version-2_backup', u'version-2']"
}
ok: [zk1-dev] => {
    "msg": "basename_array &&&&&&&& [u'version-2_backup', u'version-2']"
}
```

I would like the `basename_array` to show up as `["version-2_backup", "version-2"]`  without the *`u`* prefix

How should I change my `set fact to array` task, so I will get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `["version-2_backup", "version-2"]` is actually a JSON array, you could use the [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/to_json_filter.html).

This said, your long set of tasks looks like an overcomplicated process for a requirement that can be achieved with the right set of [`map` filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map), since map can apply the same filter to all the elements of a list, you can easily fit your `basename` in it.

So, given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      basename_array &&&&&&&&
      {{
        zookeeper_data_dir.files
          | map(attribute='path')
          | map('basename')
          | to_json
      }}
```

This yields:

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "basename_array &&&&&&&& [\"version-2_backup\", \"version-2\"]"
}
```

Note that the double quotes are escaped because you are using the JSON stdout callback. But, if you [change the callback to YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009505/ansible-stdout-formatting), this would yield exactly what you expected:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: basename_array &&&&&&&& ["version-2_backup", "version-2"]
```

Comment: Thanks.  But when I ran it, I get the this error `FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on (basename_array  {{\n  zookeeper_data_dir.files\n    | map(attribute='path')\n    | map('basename')\n    | to_json\n}}): <generator object do_map at 0x7f6395cf2a50> is not JSON serializable"}`    -    My ansible version is 2.9.7.  Is that causing me to get error for the same code that is working for you?

Comment: Yes, add a `| list` between the last map at the to_json. Or better, upgrade to a supported version of Ansible.

Comment: We can upgrade only to the latest of 2.9 ( 2.9.27 to be precise ), cannot go to higher version of ansible - 2.10 or higher.  I have already made a request to our unix admins team.  Will this work on 2.9.27 ?   Also, I am assuming - if the construct works on 2.9.27 - that instead of `debug: msg:`,  I could replace that with `set_fact: dir_list:` and then use the same construct.  Is that correct ?

Comment: `cannot go to higher version of ansible - 2.10 or higher` <= what is the justification for that? Even an archaic and totally out of date OS such as centos7 has python 3.6 available in its default repos and will let you `pip3 install ansible` in a non deprecated version either globally, as a user or in a virtualenv. Note that this is the only officially supported installation method nowadays.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, I don't have control over this.  Will check with security office, if they would allow the unix admins to update to a higher version.  Thanks for the reply